# Adding Lightning list view buttons?

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-button, page-layout, list-view

Everything I have found says to go to setup>objects>Custom Object>Search Layouts> list view layout to add buttons to the list view page of a custom object in lightning experience. I have confirmed with my org and another org that the list view layout does not appear here and the only one is the search layout. Has anyone recently added a custom button to a list view in lightning?

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding a standard button or a custom button? There might be no customizable standard buttons for the object you are trying to add it to.

[Documentation link.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331581&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: I am trying to add a custom button but the issue is that the entire list view layout is not there. It is not an option to add custom or standard buttons.